# Twitter Bootstrap: Input-append Search Box

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use Twitter Bootstrap input-append search and it's not lining up the text box and the search button. I've grabbed Twitters latest and greatest 2.1 bootstrap from August 20th (grabbed today). so things like "white-space: nowrap;" are already set.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="Search" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Search<b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ara-labelledby="Search">
 <form class="form-search">
  <div class="input-append">
   <input type="text" class="search-query">
   <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
  </div>
 </form>
</ul>
</li>
```

Sample Image:

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle with your css? Hard to troubleshoot with only html...

Comment: Have you tried having the <input> and <button> element on the same line without any space between them? like this: `<input type="text" class="search-query"><button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>`

Comment: @Kostia http://jsfiddle.net/3zx4K/1/

Comment: @John Klakegg I have tried that and receive the same results

Comment: remove margin-top: 6px; from .navbar .btn, .navbar .btn-group or override it to 0px.

Comment: That fixes the lining on the top but the text box is still smaller than the button for some reason when I run it through MAMP (locally). jsFiddle shows it properly. Ideas?

Comment: working version of the site at http://collecthw.com/ci to see whats going on (copied and pasted into jsfiddle it works, local it doesn't)

Comment: @Andrew Wilson Alright, in 2.0.4 that would have fixed it if I remember correctly. Just went through the reported issues for 2.1.0 and noticed this: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4680, even though there is no jsfiddle in that post, it looks to me that it could be the same thing you are experiencing - and it's fixed in the coming 2.1.1 patch.

Comment: @JohnKlakegg It doesn't appear to be a top margin problem any longer (after setting margin-top: to 0px. It appears that the text box looks like the text box doesn't have a vertical height set. It's off by what I think is about 5px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a proper doctype declaration. You need `<!DOCTYPE html>` over `<html>`, that's what causing the abnormality.

### Tip

I also had a look at http://collecthw.com/ci, I would strongly suggest you use http://validator.w3.org/, there are a lot of errors in the markup. Cases of `<div><form></div></form>` which obviously ain't good. I could also spot multiple `<body>` tags along with multiple versions of jquery.

I also think the markup is totally different from what bootstrap offers. Modal markup in a dropdown don't seem to be a proper thing to do.
If you follow the markup provided by [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html), and extend upon that if you wish, everything will be so much easier for you :)

Comment: !DOCTYPE completely fixed the IE issue, but Chrome, Safari, Firefox all have the same issue. I will go through the code and ensure that only 1 jquery version is referenced and that the tags are opened and closed in proper order.

Comment: Good! Might have been a bit unclear, but you need both `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>`

Comment: And it's fixed! @John Klakegg I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the button css: `margin-top: 0;`

Comment: i had the same problem and this fixed it. why it's there in the first place baffles me.

Comment: @HaykSaakian seems to be an issue with the actual search field being inside of the header... when I put it right in the body tag, it lines up fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ksokhan/3zx4K/2/